# How to Save an Array data in JSON using LARAVEL Controller

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent

I want to save this data generated by a create.blade.php view,

after I press submit button, the console log output is like the code below

```
    {
  "kode_trx": "PO-2019030004",
  "no_po": "0005/DIN/III/2019",
  "pic_po": "Carlo Donadini",
  "pic_telp": "+39438778020",
  "top": "RRRRR",
  "supplier_id": "1",
  "delivery_date": "28-03-2019",
  "created_by_id": "1",
  "total_barang": "7",
  "grand_total": "122500000",
  "tb_detail_po": [
    [
      "BRG-2019030004",
      "Electric Deep Fryer",
      "SC-81",
      "290",
      "440",
      "310",
      "4",
      "17500000",
      "70000000",
      "  ",
      "4",
      "PO-2019030004",
      "0005/DIN/III/2019",
      "1",
      "5"
    ],
    [
      "BRG-2019030004",
      "Electric Deep Fryer",
      "SC-81",
      "290",
      "440",
      "310",
      "3",
      "17500000",
      "52500000",
      "  ",
      "4",
      "PO-2019030004",
      "0005/DIN/III/2019",
      "1",
      "5"
    ]
  ]
}
```

so I want to save it into 2 differen table, table purchases and purchase_details

how I suppose to write my code in POController in method store? ???

Comment: Have you created these databases schemas already? Are you using models?

Comment: Not sure what the question is? 
Do you need help with the database schema? 
How to deal with data and converting them to easy to work with arrays or collections?
Do you need help with the Eloquent models? 
Do you need help with everything above? Then how did you manage to make create.blade.php work? I have a ton of questions.

Comment: @thisiskelvin yes I already create the database schema, I want to save data to table PO, and then table details_PO that related to table PO based on id or kode_trx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the data on table `purchase` like below

```
class POController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $purchase = Purchase::create([
            "id_penerimaan" => $request->no_nota,
            "id_customer" => $request->customer,
            "id_karyawan" => $request->karyawan,
            "tgl_penerimaan" => \Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),            
        ]);

        return $purchase;
    }
}
```

And for the table `purchase_details` if you use [Observer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#observers) it would be great

Example of Observer :

```
class UserObserver
{
    public function created(Purchase $purchase)
    {
        if (request()->tb_detail_po) {
            foreach(request()->tb_detail_po as $detail) {
                PurchaseDetail::create([
                    'id_purchase' => $purchase->id,
                    'id_penerimaan' => request()->no_nota,
                    'id_karyawan' => $detail[9],
                    'id_kategori' => $detail[8],
                    'sn_barang' => $detail[1],
                    'nama_barang' => $detail[0],
                    'kelengkapan' => $detail[2],
                    'keluhan' => $detail[3],
                    'id_garansi' => $detail[10],
                    'id_status' => '1',
                    'kondisi' => '1'
                ]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you help me with the CI syntax to laravel syntax ?

Comment: I've modified the code with data as you've asked, you can try it

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = $request->all();
$created = Your Model::create([Your Data For Table 1]);
if($created) {
   foreach($request->tb_detail_po as $details) {
      Your Model2::create([Your Detail Data For Table 2]);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try to use **JSON_DECODE($data)** OR **JSON_ENCODE($data)**
```